# How to find the optimal feature count by mRMRe package?

Tags: r, machine-learning, bioinformatics, feature-selection

I am trying to use the mRMRe package in R to do a feature selection on a gene expression dataset.I have RNA seq data containing over 10K genes  and I would like to find the optimal feature fitter the classification model. I am wondering how to find the optimal feature count. Here is my code ,

```
mrEnsemble <- mRMR.ensemble(data = Xdata, target_indices = c(1) ,feature_count = 100 ,solution_count = 1)
mrEnsemble_genes <- as.data.frame(apply(solutions(mrEnsemble)[[1]], 2, function(x, y) { return(y[x]) }, y=featureNames(Xdata)))
View(mrEnsemble_genes)
```

I just set feature_count = 100 but  I am wondering how to find the optimal feature count for classification without setting the number.
and the result after extracting mrEnsemble_genes  will be the list of genes like,

```
gene05
gene08 
gene45
gene67
```

Are they ranked by score calculated from  mutual information? I mean the first ranked gene gain the highest MI and it may be a good gene for classifying the class of sample i.e. cancer and normal, right ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the MRMR method simply ranks the N number of features you input according to their MRMR score. It is then up to you to decide which features to keep and discard.

According to the package [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mRMRe/mRMRe.pdf) of mRMRe, the MRMR score is computed as the following:

> For each target, the score of a feature is defined as the
> mutual information between the target and this feature minus the average mutual information of
> previously selected features and this feature.

So in other words,

- Relevancy = Mutual information with the target
- Redundancy = Average mutual information with the previous predictors
- MRMR Score = Relevancy - Redundancy.

The way I interpret this, the scores themselves don't offer a clear-cut answer for keeping or discarding features. Higher scores are better, but a zero / negative score does not mean the feature has no effect on the target: It could have ***some*** mutual information with the target, but ***higher*** average mutual information with the other predictors, leading to a negative MRMR score. Finding the exact optimal feature set requires experimentation.

To retrieve the indexes of the features (in the original data), ranked from highest to lowest MRMR score, use:

```
solutions(mrEnsemble)
```

To retrieve the actual MRMR scores, use:

```
scores(MrEnsemble)
```